# mongoose hook or express middleware for trigger database?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I have this schema in mongoose.
I want to delete a author that will deletes all author's stories.
is best way to do that in middleware express or middleware mongoose?
thanks

```
const authorSchema = new Schema ({
    name : String,
    stories : [{ type : ObjectId, ref:'Story'}]
})

const storySchema = new Schema({
    title : String
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it involves directly interacting with Mongoose and MongoDB, I'd suggest doing it in Mongoose middleware. Here's how you'd remove all the `stories` from a certain Author object:

```
let myAuthor = new Author(/* all the props */);
myAuthor.stories = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongoose 'remove' middleware.

For example:

```
 authorSchema.pre('remove', (next) => {
  storySchema.remove({authorSchema_id: this._id}).exec();
  next();
 });
```

And [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove).